# how to store the picture the user took in the phone and Create an internal SQLite3 database in iOS

Tags: ios5, camera

Before you give me any negative vote or comment. Read this please:

I am new to ios development, and right now I am working in this app. I have finalized the camera Api using UIImagePickerController. However, what I am trying to do is to make the user store the picture he/she took in the phone and I will create an internal SQLite3 database Store the path of where that picture is stored on the phone in the database (not the picture itself)and then Store all the info in the database. Please if you can just provide me link tutorial or any guidance, I will be very grateful. I have checked online and in stack-overflow, I could not found the answer I am looking for.

Here my Camera API code:

ViewConroller.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,         UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *Camera;

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.M

```
 #import "ViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation ViewController

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
if (![UIImagePickerController     isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

    UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                          message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                         delegate:nil
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [myAlertView show];

}


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
 {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
 - (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

  }
   - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

 }

 - (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

 }

  - (void)dealloc {
[_imageView release];
[super dealloc];
 }


 @end
```

I did it using storyboard, Xcode 4.6.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use Core Data.
A good tutorial with video can be found here: 
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

Look out for lecture 13 and 14.